# Comments vs Check-In Notes in TFS (VSTS)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008, tfvc, checkin

What's the purpose of the Check-In Notes?  Why use them instead of just the "Comment" you enter when you check-in.

I see there are four types of Check-In Notes: Code Reviewer, Developer, Security Reviewer, and Performance Reviewer.   Is the idea to put in the name of these reviewers or some actualy comments by these people.   Does this presume that you do do a team walk-through before checking-in code?  I know policies can change whether these are required, but I'm not sure what they really add on top of the "comment" field.

Comment: I got some answer here: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/77407659-32c1-477b-a874-38715bab9a4b/#59627436-6e44-4a6b-8d5d-573aa368d0eb](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/77407659-32c1-477b-a874-38715bab9a4b/#59627436-6e44-4a6b-8d5d-573aa368d0eb)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you're supposed to put the names of the people who assisted with those aspects of the checkin; and/or, their names can be added to the checkin details later when people in those roles audit the checkin.